# How to efficiently check if record exists in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I'm coding PHP kohana application and in one part of it I need to insert a few records into table.

My table structure:

```
TABLE BOOKINGS
id int
booked_object_id int
date_from date
date_tom date
```

This table has about 10k records with booked objects.

Now in one of my PHP function I have array with new data, which I want to insert into this table. There are about 20-30 new bookings to insert when my function is executed.

Now let's get to my main problem - I want it to check if ANY of bookings which I want to insert into table is already booked (object_id and date_from is the same as in my php array). If any of it is already booked, my function will not insert anything new into table.

Is there a more efficient way than getting all contents of mysql table into PHP array and check it 20 times (or number of my inserts)?

Comment: The most efficient way is to learn about the `WHERE` clause. If you do not know what it is, take a break and read some books.

Comment: No, it's not most efficient - maybe it's time for you to take some read.

Comment: It is definitely more efficient than _getting **all** contents of mysql table into PHP array_.

Comment: The answer you chose also suggests using a `WHERE` clause so I don't see why you have a problem with my comment. Let's see if someone posts _the most_ efficient way without using a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning on looking up a certain column in your table then you should index it.
This will create a hashtable that the db-server will use to lookup rows.

And as for the efficiency of making 20 calls.. you could use an `IN` statement to select all existing records in 1 call and simply ignore the already existing ones when inserting.

reference:

[expr IN (value,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: I want to check if ANY of my future inserts is already booked, if yes I don't want to insert anything :) I dont want to insert everything which is not booked already. All or nothing : ]

Comment: uhm.. did you read/understand what i wrote? let me rephrase it. "look up everything you got, don't insert the ones that come back from the SINGLE lookup"